# An SVG having only definitions for another scaling SVG still needs to scale?

Tags: svg

My SVG is `width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1200 600"`.  It uses a `clipPath` from `defs` of another SVG.

```
<svg class="svg-def">
    <defs> 
        <clipPath id="clip-1"> ...
    </defs>
</svg>


<svg width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1200 600">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip-1)">
    ...
    </g>
</svg>
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXVyob?editors=1100)**

---

When `.svg-def` does not have `width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1200 600"` (the first image), on window width narrower than 1200, the right side is clipped.  This is not desired.

I want the second image -- the clip is just the size of the SVG.   The second image is good because the `<clipPath>` being used is from an `<svg>` element with the same `width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1200 600"`

```
<svg class="svg-def">
    <defs> 
        <clipPath id="clip-1"> ...
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg class="svg-def" width="1200" height="600" viewBox="0 0 1200 600">
    <defs> 
        <clipPath id="clip-2"> ...
    </defs>
</svg>
```

---

**Questions**

1) In `<clipPath>` `<rect width="100%" height="100%"/>`,  what is 100% relative to?

2) The first clip's display width varies with window width (when the latter is narrow than 1200px).  Narrower window width = narrower display width.  What is the display width relative to?

3) So if I have an SVG which has only `<defs>`, its `<svg>` tag still has to have viewbox values, so that the other SVG which uses the definitions (and which scales with window width) can have definitions in correct sizes?

Comment: use objectBoundingBox units in your clipPaths. You won't encounter these issue then.

Comment: yes, -- and change `<rect>` to `width="1" height="1" `-- solved.